# How to delete old entries based on MAX(id) after an INSERT query?

Tags: mysql

How can I chain multiple sql queries and reuse a query result as a variable?

Specific: I want to store `MAX(id)`, persist new data, and delete the old one based on the maxid fetched before.

```
SELECT MAX(id) as maxid FROM table; //TODO how to save this?
INSERT INTO table SELECT * from temp_table...
DELELTE FROM table where id < maxid; //TODO how to reuse?
```

Comment: This is the stored routines are intended for.

Comment: Note without transactions, a query that happens before the `DELETE` has completed will see the table with its old and new values at the same time. Is this a problem/desired?

Comment: You are replacing one old row while loading several new?

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE temp LIKE real;
load up `temp`
copy 'last' from real into temp  (why??)
RENAME TABLE real TO old,
             temp TO real;
DROP TABLE old;
```

Depending on the size of the table, this could be a *lot* faster than using `DELETE`.  Also, the table is never not there.

No 'transaction' is needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are replacing the table you could use transaction

```
BEGIN
DELETE FROM table
INSERT INTO table SELECT * from temp_table...
COMMIT
```

Because its transaction, other connections will either see the whole of the old table, or the new table. If your `id` column is `AUTO_INCREMENT` then the new ids will be larger than `MAX(id)` before the insert.

Comment: That sounds what I would need. But how can I save the maxid variable in between there?

Comment: Same way as the other answer - `SELECT @maxid := max(id) FROM table` before the `DELETE`. With MariaDB-10.2 you could combine them ` WITH del_res AS (DELETE FROM table RETURNING id) SELECT @maxid : = max(id) FROM del_res`. In both cases, `@maxid` is preserved for the connection after the `COMMIT`.

Comment: correction to above - CTE `WITH` syntax is not yet correct. I should of [read the details](http://databaseblog.myname.nl/2013/11/mariadbs-returning-feature.html) before quoting some example (that was really postgresql).

Answer (score 0):

MySql allows to use [user-defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html), as others DB languages.

Here an example:

> ```
> create table tbl (id int, foo int);
> ```

> ```
> insert into tbl values (1,10),(2,20),(3,15);
> ```

> ```
> select @maxfoo := max(foo)
> from   tbl;
> ```
>
> ```
> | @maxfoo := max(foo) |
> | ------------------: |
> |                  20 |
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from   tbl
> where  foo = @maxfoo;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | foo
> -: | --:
>  2 |  20
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=176e079ffd1c083681ac6f3ffd529468)*

Comment: The user variable have a scope of connection. So it can be re-used only in the connection where it was created. If app uses connections pool (including hand-made) or if 'connection lost - reconnect', the variable will be unavailable... The best practice is in use multi-query (send all queries in one operator). Or one must use some service table in DB for to store such type of data.